# PPT file content - works in PowerPoint 2010 (and previous), unable to load in PowerPoint 2013

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I have a file saved in old PPT format.
I'm able to open it in PowerPoint 2010 and previous version.
It contains one simple macro which is not call during opening file.

When I try to open mentioned presentation in the newest PowerPoint (2013), application say that file is corrupted.
When I click on "Repair" button, I see next message which inform me that some content was not readable and has been removed. 
It virtually means that I can see only empty slides (without content) after this operation!

I tried to open mentioned PPT file in PowerPoint 2010 and use "save as" option.
When I saved it again in old PPT format, file became bigger, but I was able to open it in PP 2013.

I've tried to find a solution over the Internet, but almost everyone is talking about repairing corrupted PPT.
From my point of view it can't be corrupted, because it works great in previous PowerPoint versions.

Answer (score 0):

For the last several versions, each version of PPT has gotten fussier about what it will and won't eat.  Some little thing that earlier versions might have just ignored and gone on about their business can make later versions throw up their hands and run screaming into the night.

One trick is to "round-trip" the file to HTML and back from a version of PPT that supports it. That can weed out some of the little bits of cruft that make PPT 2013 go uncooperative.

In PPT 2010, you'll need to use VBA to do this, since the Save As HTML feature has been removed.  You can find the code on one of my FAQ pages, here:

http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ01077_How_can_I_convert_PowerPoint_2010_to_HTML_-where-s_the_Save_As_Web_Page_command--.htm

Ignore the reference at the bottom to PPT2HTML ... it's a useful add-in but won't help with this problem.